# State is not updating when using React form. I am trying to use the user input to display an order confirmation in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have tried several different methods in my handleChange function but I always log that {this.state.crust} is set to the empty string it is set to in the constructor. I am also not sure if the "name" prop is necessary in my input tag or if I should be using that in my handleChange function. Any help is much appreciated!

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      crust: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
    
    openModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

    handleCloseModal = () => {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: false
      });
    };
      
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        isOpen: true
      });
    };

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
      return (

        <div className = "form-box">
        <h5 className = "form-step"> Enter your order below </h5>
        <br />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <div className = "field1">

          <label>
            Crust : &nbsp;
            <input
              type="text"
              name={this.props.crust}
              defaultValue={this.state.crust}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="submitBtn" onClick={this.openModal}>Submit</button>

        <Modal
      show={this.state.isOpen} 
      onHide={this.closeModal}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Thank you for ordering with us, here is what you got!
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <p id="order">
            {this.state.crust}
        </p>
      </Modal.Body>

    </Modal>


        </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `value` to the input:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name={this.props.crust}
  value={this.state.crust}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)}
/>
```

There is not best practice about the input name, you can leave it like you did.

Comment: Whenever I pass in value I cannot type in the field

Comment: that's strange it's working well here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-field-eunqg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by taking "crust" out of my constructor. I assume that the constructor was not allowing the value of this.state.crust to change from the empty string.